# Area Between Curves with Integrals

Tags: calculus

Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to x or y. Draw a typical approximating rectangle.

let $f(x) = x^2-2x $

let $g(x)=4x+7$

$y = x^2 − 2x,  y = 4x + 7$

I set both of the functions equal to each other

$x^2 -2x = 4x +7$

$0=-(x^2-6x+7)$

factoring out led to
$(x-7)(x+1)$

so the integral I obtained was $\int_{-1}^{7}(f(x)dx-g(x)dx)$

$\int_{-1}^{7}(x^2-6x-7)dx$

$x^3/3-3x^2-7x\mid _{-1}^{7}$

And then I'm lost from here.

Comment: Note that $f(x)-g(x)$ simply is a polynomial

Comment: You are there. Just evaluate the integral. One note: you didn't check if $f(x) > g(x)$ or $f(x) < g(x)$ in the range $[-1, 7]$ but you can just take the absolute value of your answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you I wasn't using the absolute value of my answer. The answer is 256/3